# Can I use copyright content in my iOS app? Who take the risk Apple or me?

Tags: ios-appstore, copyright

I plan to start a quiz app to help people learn english. I would use a well know dictionary for it. I do not want to use 3rd party free dictionary, because there is a big difference in quality. This dictionary prevent any commercial usage of their dictionary.

Who takes risk after I submitted the app and Apple approved it? Me or Apple?

What if user will upload the content to CloudKit from GUI and not me?

What if phisically I do not store data only always forward the query to their online database, and I only present it?

Here are the exact rules: *Users are not entitled to modify the content of this Site or reproduce, republish, distribute, transmit, link, frame or deep-link it on any other website without the express permission of Pearson. > Users may not distribute, transmit, reproduce or publish by electronic or any other means any part of the data without the prior written permission of Pearson. > Users may not create a database in electronic or structured manual form by systematically downloading and storing all or any of the content. > All other rights reserved.*

from [here](http://uk.pearson.com/legal-notice)

Comment: You are. Regardless of what is in Apples agreements. You are in an agreement with the dictionary vendor. Which YOU would be breaking.(transmit) I also think this is off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really about licensing laws.

Comment: you have a  `copyright` tag for it, on stackoverflow I can not ask, because not programming, here neither, then where? SA should have a law section ..

Comment: Any =one who knows the law e.g. a lawyer probably has rules about advice they can give and this is usually if in direct contact - thus any l=legal advice on the web is not of much use. You have to get yor own lawyer for legal advice

Comment: @mark you are right, but when talking lawyer, you need preconcept, you need to ask meaningful question, I heard this and that, can you approve? layer does a 'compilation validation process' you can make his job easier, giving him the ingredients, where to look for, what you heard, etc., as programmer I get specification to translate it into digital product, layer needs input too, to translate it into contract, I guess

Comment: This is primarily a legal question and not directly related to the topics covered in the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Apple has to approve your app before they allow it onto any of their App stores, but they often can't check every line of text for copyright infringement. Since all they do is host the app on the App Store, it is still your responsibility as the creator for any copyright infringements.